# Schema hRecipe fn / name not working?

Tags: seo, markup, schema.org, microformats, recipe

I have published various recipes on a website wrapping my elemnts with hRecipe schema. I can get all of my schema elments to work except for the name / fn to work? i am unsure why this is as i have stated within my code where the name is.

As you can see i have written:

```
<article class="twelve columns hrecipe" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
<h1 itemprop="name">Crispy Sussex fish goujons</h1>
```

Which should mean that it would fine the name. also you can see in googles structured data testing tool, and it still cannot find it?

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Flocalfoodbritain.com%2Frecipes%2Fcrispy-sussex-fish-goujons%2F

Also i wonder if anyone can advise me as to why the image is not displaying in the preview?

Here is the live web page / code does anyone have any ideas?

http://localfoodbritain.com/recipes/crispy-sussex-fish-goujons/

```
<article class="twelve columns hrecipe" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
<h1 itemprop="name">Crispy Sussex fish goujons</h1>
<p>Our recipe uses the freshest fish; locally-caught Sussex pollock brought into <a title="Veasey and Sons" href="/sussex/shops/fishmongers/veasey-and-sons/">Veasey and Sons fishmongers</a>&nbsp;by their boat that fishes between Eastbourne and Poole Bay. To serve, why not try a dollop of Sussex Gold Award winning Sussex Valley Classic Mayonnaise&nbsp;from&nbsp;<a title="The Condiment Company" href="/sussex/food/condiments/the-condiment-company/">The Condiment Company of Chichester</a>?</p><div id="recipe" class="sollos_recipe">
<div class="row">
<div class="recipe-main"><img itemprop="image" src="http://localfoodbritain.com/files/9713/9816/6500/Fish_goujons_small.jpg" width="550" height="416" alt="Crispy Sussex fish goujons"><p class="intro" itemprop="description">Freshly made fish goujons dipped in creamy mayonnaise make a tasty change from sandwiches for picnics. You could nip to the shops and buy them, but there really is nothing like making your own. It guarantees beautifully succulent fish and the crispiest batter.</p>
<hr>
<br>
   <h3 class="sollos_recipe_secion-header">Ingredients</h3>
  <ul class="ingredients sollos_recipe_ingredients" itemprop="ingredients">
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">450</span> 
                  <span class="type">g</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">firm white fish fillet, skinned and boned </span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">Juice</span> 
                  <span class="type">of</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">1 large lemon</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">3</span> 
                  <span class="type">tbsp</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">plain flour</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">1</span> 
                  <span class="type">dessertspoon</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">chopped fresh parsley</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">1</span> 
                                </span> 
              <span class="name">large free-range egg</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">80</span> 
                  <span class="type">g</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">fresh white breadcrumbs</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">Pinch</span> 
                                </span> 
              <span class="name">salt and freshly ground black pepper</span>
          </li>
                <li class="ingredient sollos_recipe_ingredient"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              <span class="amount">
                  <span class="value">25</span> 
                  <span class="type">g</span>              </span> 
              <span class="name">melted butter</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
<hr>
<br>

        <h3 class="sollos_recipe_secion-header">Preparation</h3>
        <ol class="instructions sollos_recipe_instructions" itemprop="recipeInstructions">
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Slice the fish fillets into strips, fairly thick and about 2cm wide then put them in a shallow dish with the lemon juice. Pop in the fridge and leave for at least half an hour.</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">When you’re ready to make the goujons, preheat the oven to 220°C (gas 7).</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Put the flour in a shallow bowl and season with salt and pepper.</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Place the egg in another bowl and beat it lightly.</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Mix the parsley with the breadcrumbs and spread onto a plate.</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Gently roll the fish in the seasoned flour mixture. Next, dip each piece in the beaten egg and then into the breadcrumbs until it is nicely coated. Place the goujons on a lightly oiled, non-stick, baking tray. </li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Pop in the oven for 10 minutes, turning halfway through cooking. Brush with the melted butter and return to the oven until golden, which will take about another 5 minutes.</li> 
                            <li class="instruction sollos_recipe_instruction">Cool and then carefully pack into a sealed container ready for your picnic!</li> 
                    </ol>
         </div>    
<div class="recipe-side">
                <div class="retailer-block">
                                              <h4>Serves <span class="yield">4-6</span></h4> <hr>                   

                            <h4><span class="prepTime"><meta itemprop="prepTime" content="PT45M">
                        <span class="value-title" title="PT45M"></span>
                    </span>
                    45 minutes.
                </h4>
                <p><small>Preparation time</small></p>
                <hr>   



                            <h4><span class="cookTime"><meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT15M">
                        <span class="value-title" title="PT15M"></span>
                    </span>
                    15 minutes.
                </h4>
                <p><small>Cooking time</small></p>
                <hr> 


                                     <h4><span itemprop="recipeCuisine">British</span></h4>
            <p><small>Cuisine</small></p> <hr>

                            <h4><span itemprop="recipeCategory">Main Course</span></h4>
                <p><small>Type of dish</small></p> 

                </div>        
                <a class="addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=300&amp;pubid=xa-515e95777e2ce970">
                 <div class="btn btn-medium btn-full-width btn-category align-center"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share</div>
                 </a>


<p class="mb-none"><small>Recipe Contributed by</small></p>
<h5><span class="author" itemprop="author">Tracy Carroll</span></h5>

        <p class="sollos_recipe_publish-date">Published 
    <span class="published" itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-04-23T10:22:29-01:00">
    <span class="value-title" title="2014-04-23T10:22:29-01:00"> </span>2014-04-23T10:22:29-01:00</span></p>    
<div class="tags"><hr><h5>Tags</h5><a href="http://localfoodbritain.com/blogsearch/Fish/">Fish</a></div></div></div></div>                  </article><!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Microformats (making use of the [hRecipe Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hrecipe)) and Microdata (making use of the schema.org vocabulary, especially [its `Recipe` type](http://schema.org/Recipe)) (as well as RDFa making use of the Open Graph vocabulary, but this is unrelated to your recipes).

On the `article` element, you are specifying both:

- `class="hrecipe"` (= Microformat)
- `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"` (= Microdata)

But on the `h1`, you add the name only for one:

- `itemprop="name"` (= Microdata)

So if you want to add this name in Microformats, too, you’d have to add the `fn` class to the `h1`:

```html
<h1 itemprop="name" class="fn">Crispy Sussex fish goujons</h1>
```

In the *Google Structured Data Testing Tool*, the parsed Microformat is in the box titled "hrecipe", the parsed RDFa is in the box titled "rdfa-node", and the parsed Microdata is in the boxes titled "Item".